Upgrade from Buster to Bullseye now reports Release file not found in s3 bucket for private repo apt update
I upgraded our Debian kernel from Buster to Bullseye on our device. However, when trying to update our custom Debian packages from our s3 using apt repo, I now receive a message that the repository doesn't have a Release file. However it is in the repo and another device on Buster can still get the updates successfully.
Aptly version 1.4.0 was used to publish the Debian packages to the s3 bucket. Our Buster device is using gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12  with libcrypt 1.8.4 and the Bullseye device is using gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27 with libcrypt 1.8.8.
I have tried to manually pull the Release file and load it into the trusted.gpg.d in Bullseye. It appears to work. The key is listed as expected but I still receive the error. I've tried to pull the public key and run it through --dearmor and copy into the trusted.gpg.d. Again everything looks like it should work but doesn't.
What am I missing here?
